# How to find the speed to maximise the distance travelled

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I'm given that a car travels at speed along its track it uses fuel at a rate of

$R(v)=17‌v^2 –7v+7$, in litres per sec.

Where $v$ is the speed in metres per second.
The fuel tank holds $Y$ litres of fuel:

$$Y = \int_{0}^{T}  R(v(t))\,dt$$

$v(t)$ is the speed as a function of the time.

I found the speed to maximise the time the car travels under power which was $v = 7/34$.

How should I find the what constant speed the car must run to maximize the distance $vT$ that it runs under power?

Any help would be great, thank you.

Edit: I integrated $Y = \frac{17T^3}{3} - \frac{7T}{2} +7T$, I'm not sure what else to do, after following Nurator's suggestion. Calculus is my weakest topic.

Comment: With a given $R(v(t))$ and constant $v$ you can just calculate the integral and solve for your unknown $v$

Comment: $\displaystyle Y = \int_0^{T} R(v) ~dv. ~$ That is, in line with the comment of @Nurator, the function $~R(v)~$ is independent of the time.

Comment: You already found $v$ so that $T$ is maximized. (It's $v = 7/34$.) Now you want $v$ so that $vT$ is maximized.

Comment: @user2661923 $dv$ in the previous comment should be $dt$. I assume that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to find the constant speed $v$ of the car in order to maximise the distance $vT$ that it runs, we should proceed in the following way :

$Y=\displaystyle\int_0^T\!\!R(v(t))\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^T\!\!R(v)\,\mathrm dt=R(v)T\;,\;\;\;$ hence ,

$T=\dfrac Y{R(v)}\;,\;\;\;$ consequently ,

we need to calculate the maximum of the function

$f(v)=vT=\dfrac{vY}{R(v)}=\dfrac{vY}{17v^2-7v+7}$

where $\,Y\,$ is a positive constant.

On the other hand ,

$\begin{align}f(v)&=\dfrac{vY}{17v^2-7v+7}=\dfrac Y{17v-7+\frac7v}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac Y{\left(\sqrt{17v}-\sqrt{\frac7v}\right)^2+2\sqrt{119}-7}\leqslant\\[3pt]&\leqslant\dfrac Y{2\sqrt{119}-7}\;\;\text{ for any } v>0\;.\end{align}$

Moreover ,

$f(v)=\dfrac Y{2\sqrt{119}-7}\iff\sqrt{17v}=\sqrt{\dfrac7v}\iff v=\sqrt{\dfrac7{17}}\;.$

Consequently ,

$\max\{f(v)\}=\max\{vT\}=\dfrac Y{2\sqrt{119}-7}\;\;\;$ and

the constant speed $v$ of the car in order to maximise the distance $vT$ that it runs, is

$v=\sqrt{\dfrac7{17}}\;.$